# When do I need to create new instance of the List?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

When do I need to choose one or the other method for lists? What about the resources we use?

`List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(something.getList);`

`List<String> names = something.getList;`

Comment: This is up to you. If you want to share the list and be manage by multiple source, use the same instance, if you want the list to evolve separatly (remove an item in only one of those), then to a duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this `List<String> names = something.getList;` assigns another reference to the `something.getList` object namely `names`. With the other syntax you get a brand new `names` object. As for which to use, is it actually a question of what you need, if you need to pass around a list i'd suggest you to use an  [Immutable List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)).

Comment: You should develop a bit more on the difference between having a new list with `ArrayList(Collection)` and using the reference. But nice suggestion about `Collections.unmodifiableList`

Answer (score 0):

This is the preferred way to do things, it means later on you can change the `List` of `names` to be of a different implementation of `List` because `List` is the interface and `ArrayList` is the comcrete implementation. Later in life you may want to change this to be a `LinkedList` or other implementation that uses the `List` interface.

I would do like this:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(something.getList());
```

Comment: which one is the preferred way you say?

Comment: I updated my answer. I would do ``List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(something.getList);``

Comment: The point is not there. One create a new instance of the list, the other get the original list reference. And the fact that you have an `ArrayList` doesn't change anything on the usage of `names`, only `List` methods are visible from `names` (without a cast).